# PostgreSQL best way to have different progressive id for different users?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with a `members` table where the members is stored, something like

| id | email | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | email@email.com | row |
| 2 | email2@email.com | row |

And another table that stores ( let's say ) `posts`

| id | member_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hello World 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Hello World 2 |
| 3 | 2 | Word hello 1 |
| 4 | 2 | Word hello 2 |

What i would achieve is to have a different id counter for every user though.
Something like this

| id | member_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Hello World |
| 2 | 1 | Hello World |
| 1 | 2 | Word hello |
| 2 | 2 | Word hello |

Maybe even something like this

| main_id | id | member_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Hello World |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Hello World |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | Word hello |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | Word hello |

Of course I could create a key using both `id` and `member_id` to make them unique. In that case I cannot use the counter for the auto increment though. I should calculate the new id using some logic backend side.

What i was wondering is if there is any way to let Postgres do it by himself. Giving the `member_id` postgres should automatically assign the next available index for that member as would do with a normal counter.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `row_number()` window function will generate an index starting from `1` based on a group and/or an order.

An index will be globally created by the first `row_number()`. the second row_number(), will create an index based on each member.

```
select row_number() over( order by m.id) as main_id,
       row_number() over(partition by m.id) as id,
       p.member_id,
       p.content
from members m
inner join posts p on p.member_id = m.id
```

Regarding the `main_id` you also have the option to use the `Post id` instead :

```
select p.id as main_id,
       row_number() over(partition by m.id) as id,
       p.member_id,
       p.content
from members m
inner join posts p on p.member_id = m.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mcax-8CY)

Comment: Why use `row_number()` for the `main_id` instead of [just the post id](https://dbfiddle.uk/5k-V7aVm)?

Comment: Btw I would recommend identity columns as primary keys: https://dbfiddle.uk/mzj4c4Ns

Comment: Umh, I should also use the post Id to be referred in other tables though. Using that way I can only get it on the select queries and if I delete a post the id will mismatch